# Investigating a Java bug regarding String.valueOf(float)

Tags: java, locale

In Java is it a possibility that String.valueOf(float) would format a float number differently based on what operating system the code is run on, the version of java and/or the operating systems locale.

For example, with the float number 4.5 would it ever be formatted to "4,5" instead of "4.5"?

Comment: not, if you specify the correct locale. And otherwise ( unstated locale ) its a feature.

Comment: OS and locale: no, they should be identical. Java version: possibly, but very very unlikely: this is fundamental enough behaviour that you'd upset a lot of people if you changed it between versions.

Comment: @AndyTurner Not possible. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)

Comment: @Najzero This has nothing to do with locales.

Comment: @Marko this is my point: the behaviour (including locale insensitivity) is described in the Javadoc, so it could - maybe, remotely - have changed between versions, but it would be the same for the same version on different OS.

Comment: @AndyTurner "Possibly" sounds at least two orders of magnitude more likely than it actually is :) This is a method from JDK 1.0 and Java never changes contracts of anything.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try to probe the user if he can tell me his java version.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am indeed not 100% sure, as the docs state otherwise, but I remember the exact same example from a customer installation ( load balanced over country borders ) where this was kinda the fault. Reason was a globally set locale ( by `setlocale` ) that did this funny junk.

Comment: @Najzero No, it definitely did not come from `Float.toString` or `String.valueOf`. There are other mechanisms which are locale-sensitive; this is not one of them.

Comment: For reference, here's the Javadoc of JDK 1.2 method: http://www.kbs.twi.tudelft.nl/Documentation/Programming/Java/jdk1.2/api/index.html

Comment: @Marko ok, how about "about as likely as a Trump presidency". Oh wait...

Comment: _(...) is it a possibility that String.valueOf(float) would format a float number differently (...)?_ The answer to that would be "no". But it is very possible that the String returned by `valueOf(float)` is being further transformed using `NumberFormat`, `String.format()` or even externally to Java (e.g. Excel will change thousands and decimals delimiters to comply with OS locale rules when importing text as number).

Comment: @AndyTurner My estimate of that likelihood seems to be different than yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.valueOf(float)` calls `Float.toString()`.

`Float.toString()` calls intern `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString(float)`

The result string will never contain the sign `,` bacause of hard-coded `'.'` (ASCII: 46) inside the `BinaryToASCIIBuffer.getChars(chars[])`

You can see it if you decompile `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal` class (in my case java 8 jdk) or see the [(similar) implementation in openjdk.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.getChars%28char[]%29)